# Upgrade from 2007 to 2010 - broken features

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, publishing, asmx

I have been handed a site that was upgraded from 2007 to 2010.

When I try to publish a workflow to the site using Sharepoint Designer I receive the error that the formservices.asmx file is missing.

[image]

In other words designer cannot connect to the webservice which publishes workflows.

Is this normal for a site upgraded from 2010 and what is the resolution?

thanks in advance.

KS

Comment: Can you post your exact error messages?  Also, check the Event Viewer and ULS logs on the SharePoint server for any errors logged when you try to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate Access Mapping was not configured in Central Admin for the internal url.

thanks.